# Dual of $L^1[a,b]$ is $L^{\infty}[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I know that the tricky part is to prove that the map $\alpha$ that takes any $f \in L^{\infty}[a,b]$ ans sends it to $K_f$, where $K_f(g) = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$ and $g \in L^1[a,b]$ is surjective and isometric. The rest I have already done it.

I have seen a couple of proofs on this site about this fact using the famous Radon–Nikodym theorem. However, they usually work with abstract spaces $X$ and measures $\mu$. In my case it suffices to work with $X=[a,b]$ and with the Lebesgue measure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ has finite mesure so $L^2 \subset L^1$ and thus every linear form $\ell$ on $L^1$ is (by Hilbert space magic) given on $L^2$ by the integration against some $L^2$ function $f$.

Assume that $|\ell(g)| \leq M$ if $\|g\|_{L^1} \leq 1$. Let $S=\{f > M+1\}$. Then $|\ell(1_S)| \leq M\lambda(S)$, but $\int{f1_S} \geq \lambda(S) (M+1)$. Thus $\lambda(S)=0$ and it follows by a similar argument that $|f| \leq M+1$ almost everywhere, thus $f$ is in $L^{\infty}$. Now $\ell$ and the integral against $f$ coincide on  $L^2$ (a dense subset of $L^1$) and they’re both continuous so they’re equal.

So $f \longmapsto K_f$ is a bijection. The above argument (suitably modified) shows that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|K_f\|_{(L^1)^*}$. But it’s easy to see that $\|K_f\|_{(L^1)^*} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: What theorem are you actually using when you say by Hilbert's space magic?

Comment: Every continuous linear form is the inner product against some vector.

Comment: It seems to me that your $\ell$ is not some arbitrary function in $(L^1[a,b])^*)$, but one that satisfies $|\ell(g)| \leq \| g \|_{L^1}\leq M$ for all $g$. If true then we have just showed that only those functions have corresponding $f$'s that are in $L^{\infty}[a,b]$.

Comment: That’s a typo. I think this argument works for all continuous linear $\ell: L^1([a,b]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have fixed it. Just need to check the inequality $\| f  \|_{\infty}  \leq \| K_f  \|_{(L^1[a,b])^*}$

Comment: The argument above shows that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|K_f\|+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$, by replacing the $M+1$ with $M+\epsilon$.

Comment: That actually proves they are equal, right ?

Comment: Yes, this proves the equality.